# How to join NSArray elements into an NSString?

Tags: cocoa, string

Given an NSArray of NSStrings, is there a quick way to join them together into a single NSString (with a Separator)?

Comment: I must be blind! or tired. or both...

Comment: If you search the NSString docs for this, you will never find it.  Its in NSArray!

Answer (score 316, accepted):

```
NSArray * stuff = /* ... */;
NSString * combinedStuff = [stuff componentsJoinedByString:@"separator"];
```

This is the inverse of `-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]`.

Answer (score 12):

[`-componentsJoinedByString:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString:) on NSArray should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There's also this variant, if your original array contains Key-Value objects from which you only want to pick one property (that can be serialized as a string ):

```
@implementation NSArray (itertools)

-(NSMutableString *)stringByJoiningOnProperty:(NSString *)property separator:(NSString *)separator
{
    NSMutableString *res = [@"" mutableCopy];
    BOOL firstTime = YES;
    for (NSObject *obj in self)
    {
        if (!firstTime) {
            [res appendString:separator];
        }
        else{
            firstTime = NO;
        }
        id val = [obj valueForKey:property];
        if ([val isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            [res appendString:val];
        }
        else
        {
            [res appendString:[val stringValue]];
        }
    }
    return res;
}


@end
```

Comment: There is a memory leak in your code, mutableCopy retains the object it is copying, hence you would need to do return [res autorelease] at the end.  Also there is no reason to do mutablecopy instead of just making a mutablestring straight off the bat.

Comment: @thewormsterror : forgot to mention this code was for ARC. Also, the mutablecopy call is the modern objective-c convention for creating mutable version of objects using  @-syntax ( such as [@[] mutablecopy] for a mutable nsarray). don't know what a difference it makes performance wise.