# parsing a particular time format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsdate

I am getting a time/duration from a .NET web service in this format: `PT12H30M`

How can this be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the format string for parsing a date you use the [UTS #35 Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) to define what the incoming data looks like. PT looks like a legitimate timezone abbreviation. You will want to fiddle with this depending on whether the minutes and hours are zero-padded or not.

```
NSString *dateString = @"PT12H30M";
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ZZhh'H'mm'M'"];
NSDate date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateString];
```

Comment: Ah I see, I wasn't sure if I could convert this into an NSDate object. Thanks!

Comment: NSString *dateString = @"PT12H30M";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ZZhh'H'mm'M'"];
                NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
                
                NSLog(@"%@", date);
                [dateFormatter release]; Seems to print out null. Any Ideas?

Comment: I wonder if it is PT that is not recognised. Try replacing the ZZ with 'PT' (note it is quoted like the 'H' and 'M'.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. Also, it seems like I am getting a different time but this maybe due to the timezone?                NSString *dateString = @"PT12H30M";
                NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"'PT'hh'H'mm'M'"];
                NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
                
                NSLog(@"%@", date);
                [dateFormatter release]; returns 1970-01-01 08:30:00 +0000

Comment: Oh I think PT should use v instead of Z

Comment: How does someone who marks correct an answer containing code which does not compile (http://stackoverflow.com/q/1387440/189804) write such a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which can parse dates with a user-specified format using [particular syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1). Parse result is a standard NSDate.

Comment: Wasn't sure if you could convert this into NSDate. Cool thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of NSDateFormatter configured with a format string the describes the time format, and then use the `-dateFromString:` method to translate the time you get from the web service into a NSDate object.